# Shimming a control

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I'm trying to write some unit tests on some legacy code using MSTest. I've added a fakes assembly on the class I'm testing, but it has a reference to a user control and that has code behind in it. 
I know this is probably not the right way to go about it, but is it possible to Shim a user control? They don't show up in the ShimContext, so I'm not holding out too much hope..

Comment: What would help answer your question is if you point out to which control you are referring - aspx, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: Very good point. Doh. It's WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got stuck.

If i create a new class `UserControl1` in WPF like so:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
  {
    public UserControl1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Do()
    {

    }
  }
```

Then my generated shim contains the `Do()` method:

`Namespace.Fakes.ShimUserControl1.AllInstances.Do = control1 => { };`

If you want to shim the actual `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`, reference `PresentationFramework` dll and generate fakes for it.

Then you will get the following instance properties to assign (see screenshot):
[image: Screenshot]